# Open link when user changes date in date picker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dom-events

I am using a Twitter Bootstrap datepicker (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

What I am trying to do is use the input value (e.g. 15-02-2012 ) to load a page, when the user changes the date.

The input box uses this code:

```
    <div class="input-append date"  data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd- mm-yyyy">
    <input class="span9" size="16" id="dp3" type="text" value="12-02-2012" onchange="myFunction()">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
```

And the JavaScript to reload the page is this:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
datevalue = document.getElementById("dp3").value
window.open(datevalue,"_self");
}
</script>
```

The problem is when the date is changed in the date picker (input id = dp3), nothing happens, the page does not reload, but when I tried attaching `myFunction()` to another text box, it does work, and it is able to grab the value in the datepicker (dp3).

So the problem is that JavaScript is not recognising the change in value of the datepicker (id=dp3). Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you took the code from the example n°3 of your link, but you switched the `id` to the wrong tag.

```
                       Here  --.
                               V
<div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" readonly="">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

If you leave the id on the `input` tag and keep the original JS code, the `.datepicker()` method will be called on the wrong element (the input): it is meant to be called on the parent div.

Then, on your jQuery, you should bind the `changeDate` event of your date-picker, and not the `onChange` of the `input` tag itself.

You could try something like this (using jQuery) :

```
$('#dp3').datepicker().on('changeDate', function() {
    //Retrieve the date located on the data of your datepicker
    var datevalue = $('#dp3').data("date");

    //You can take the value from the input as well if you want
    //The input tag doesn't really need an ID to be retrieved (see comments)
    //var datevalue = $('#dp3 input').val();

    window.open(datevalue,"_self");
});
```

**Edit** : here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/GWsSV/) with minor changes.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work... On changing the date nothing happened. Some reason it's not recognising the change. Are you sure about not needing an id for the text input, because this is where the value is stored, and using JavaScript I can retrieve a value from the input field, but not from the <div class="input append date">

Comment: Actually... still a bug. On change it does successfully open the link. But it is always opening the link of the starting value of the text box "12/02/2012" - instead of opening the new value chosen by the datepicker. Do you know why this is?

Comment: I have found a way that works, instead of using the div, I'm just using a text box as input -> <input class="span9" size="16" id="dp3" type="text" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" 
         value=<%= @s_date.strftime("%a-%d-%b-%Y") %> style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center"> and for the function $('#dp3').datepicker().on('changeDate', function() {
    //Retrieve the date located on the data of your datepicker
    var datevalue = $('#dp3').val();
    window.open('schedules?sdate=' + datevalue, "_self");
});

Comment: @switcher If you let `#dp3` as an ID on the wrapping div, you'll have two identical IDs on the DOM, which is a really bad practice; consider using the second solution I provided you (the one commented in the code box) instead of giving another class or id to the `input` tag.

Comment: just coming back to this - for what it's worth I figured out what I was doing wrong, and your solution was completely right.. I'm using it properly now (y)